# Null Pointer exception when trying to return HashMap value in java

Tags: java, pointers, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I'm working on my java project and get a null pointer exception message when trying to return HashMap value.

```
public class NgramModel
{
    private HashMap<String,Integer> ngram; 

    public NgramModel() 
    {
        HashMap<String,Integer> ngram = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        ngram.put("aa", 2);
    }

    public HashMap<String,Integer> getValue() {
        return ngram;
    }
}
```

When my JUnit test gets to the line:

```
assertEquals(2,(int)test.getValue().get("aa"));
```

I have got: no exception message. And the test crashes.

Comment: You're shadowing your instance variable in your constructor.

Comment: @ZouZou this is the answer, don't you want to write it in the big text-area?

Comment: Sorry I don't fully get it.

Comment: @ZouZou Show him how it's done in the answers ;)

Comment: @user2758935 Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: @hgoebl / Aarowaim Too lazy to write one :) Go ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand variable shadowing.

Begin with a simple example, not using a constructor:

```
static int test = 10;

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    int test = 20;
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

What does this code print?

The answer is `20`. The reason is that the `test` you declare in the method is actually a *different* `test` to the one you declare in the class. You have two variables in different scopes.

You have the same issue here:

```
public class NgramModel {

    //one `ngram`
    private HashMap<String,Integer> ngram; 

    public NgramModel() {
        //a second `ngram`
        HashMap<String,Integer> ngram = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        ngram.put("aa", 2);
    }
}
```

You do **not** need to redeclare the variable:

```
public class NgramModel {

    //one `ngram`
    private HashMap<String,Integer> ngram; 

    public NgramModel() {
        //reference the `ngram` from above
        ngram = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        ngram.put("aa", 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The field ngram is still null, as you are declaring a new variable (ngram) in the scope of the constructor. Try the following:

```
public NgramModel() {
  ngram = new HashMap...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way-

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NgramModel
{
    private HashMap<String,Integer> ngram; 

    public NgramModel() 
    {
        ngram = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        ngram.put("aa", 2);
    }

    public HashMap<String,Integer> getValue() {
        return ngram;
    }
}
```

OR

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NgramModel
{
    private HashMap<String,Integer> ngram = new HashMap <String, Integer>(); 

    public NgramModel() 
    {
        ngram.put("aa", 2);
    }

    public HashMap<String,Integer> getValue() {
        return ngram;
    }
}
```

Because, inside your constructor you are creating another local variable and defining it and not defining the class level member variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

The instance member of map type will always be null, if not initialized. In this case, you should rephrase your code something, like that

```
public class NgramModel
{
    private Map<String,Integer> ngram; 

    public NgramModel() {
        ngram = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        ngram.put("aa", 2);
    }

    public Map<String,Integer> getValue() {
        return ngram;
    }
}
```

And do not type any members/variables with implementations. You should be typing with interfaces, if it's possible.